# Can't activate wireless from WingPanel for Toshiba

Tags: wifi, release-hera

On a Toshiba  Satellite C75D-B7260. I can not figure out how to get the driver for this model.Or if that is the problem. Thanks

Comment: I'm reinstalling with third party.

Answer (score 0):

So that the Wifi card almost always works do not forget to check the option

**Install third-party software for graphics Wi-Fi Hardware and additionalmedia formats**

in the window **Update and other software** during the installation

Comment: I reinstalled it three times with all the available check marks no luck.

Comment: Could you put in your response the result of the following command: `lshw -class network`. You may need a specific driver for your network card.